# Can not bind in angular

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular.
Trying to use the ng-model directive for 2 way binding

I have tried 2 ways to do it

```
<!-- <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" ngModel name ="email"> -->
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" [(ngModel)]="email">
```

Both of them are described above

First one is working where and second is not

Could you please explain me the problem in the second line which is not working using [(ngModel)].

Is this an incorrect syntax?

Forms module is already imported in app.module.ts

Comment: Insufficient context and vague description of problem as "not working"

Comment: Please make sure that you have following import in your module:



import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the name attribute in the input field to bind form with name

or

use [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

```html
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" [(ngModel)]="email">

<input type="email" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" [(ngModel)]="email">
```

` id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" [(ngModel)]="email">

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the following import in your module:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

For more details, you can refer to official documentation here:

https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#ngmodel-two-way-binding

Edit: This is a very basic example, using your input element as-is:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anjdwq?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I did that in both component class file and also in ap.module.ts file. But it is giving  error : If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

Comment: Please check this example that I added to my answer as well: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anjdwq?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Hi Umair, This example seems to have an error . Input does not seem to be displayed. Could you please fix it. At present preview seems to be blank

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using `ngForm`. In that case, all the input fields which have `[(ngModel)]=""` must have an attribute `name` with a value.

```html
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" [(ngModel)]="email" name="email">
```